# building a group from a list of email addresses of contacts

Tags: groups, search-builder, custom-search

I have a list of email addresses of contacts. I want to create a group out of those contacts. What would be the easiest way to do that on 4.5.3 ?

Note, the `IN` operator of the search builder doesn't seem to work on 4.5.3. it basicly always returns 'sorry'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not able find a search method that results in the people you want to add to a group. And you have a list of email addresses of the people in the group. You can use the import feature.

The import allows you to add contacts (newly imported or existing matched contacts) in to a group.

Contacts > Import Contacts ("For Duplicate Contacts" use Update)